# How to create a global variable in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm new with laravel and I need some help to understand how to create a global variable that can be used everywhere inside templates.

For example, I want to query data from `users` table with `->leftjoin` table and get the results for the current users in all blade templates which are configured to use different Controllers.

For example...

```
$user = DB::table('users')
->leftJoin('groups', 'groups.id', '=', 'users.group')
->select('users.*, groups.*)
->whereRaw('where user.id = (current_user need help here)')
-first();
```

Should allow the use of...

```
@if($user->groups.name != 'Admin')
You are not admin
@endif
```

In all blade templates...

Comment: You can write some middleware that does this and does a global share to the view so you can use it everywhere. https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

Answer (score 0):

you can create in the appServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
 $user = DB::table('users')
 ->leftJoin('groups', 'groups.id', '=', 'users.group')
  ->select('users.*, groups.*)
  ->whereRaw('where user.id = (current_user need help here)')
   -first();
    View::share('user', $user);
}
```

and then you can use it in every view,
remember to import this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use App\User;
```

Comment: Can I use if else there from auth to check if current user is authenticated?

Comment: Adding it to `AppServiceProvider.php` gives `Undefined variable $user` in the blade template

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, I know three ways to share variables to all views:

- Using `View::share` in the `boot` method of a service provider. The variable is assigned the value when the service provider is booted.
- Using a view composer (`View::composer`). The variable is assigned the value just before the template is rendered.
- Using a view creator (`View::creator`). The variable is assigned the value right after the view object is initiated.

Laravel has documentation for all of these three approaches:

- https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#sharing-data-with-all-views
- https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#view-composers

Comment: Thank you for response, I tried it, but I'm getting $user is undefined when trying to add it into blade. Any chance you can write example for the first way?